# File not found on input line with latex command

Tags: graphics, input

I am editing tex file document I have started 4 months ago, which was working like a charm since today. I am actually working on a new computer (Win7 environment) and first installed MiKTeX + TeXMaker. I switched to TeXLive as MiKTex was not working as I expected and was not able to find some packages I am using in my tex file. I have removed MiKTeX BEFORE switching to TeXLive and changed the path in TeXMaker. The version with

> tex --version

is effectively TeXLive. The file can compile (no errors on packages or anything else) but is not able to find my pictures (all of them), with the following errors :

> ! Package pdftex.def Error: File `Pictures/EVscheme.jpeg' not found:
>   using draf t setting.
>
> See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation. Type  H
>     for immediate help.  ...

I know there is a lot of topics about this, but mostly for new documents. This is an old one which was working perfectly and stored on a private git, so no one modified it. The file extension is good. 
I have tried the following :

```
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\epstopdfsetup{outdir=./}
```

which is not working. I have also tried \graphicspath, but its not working too. This is not surprising me too much, as it was working perfectly fine without these commands. 
The strangest part now : the pdflatex  command works perfectly. The latex  command is not able to find the pictures. Is there any reason with this ?

Comment: Did you tries `\graphicspath{{./Pictures}}`? (Then you have to look for "Pictures/EVscheme.jpeg" by a search and remove the "Pictures" to leave only "EVscheme.jpeg")... Have you done somethinh like this?

Comment: Yup I did this and its not working. But however I think the problem is deeper as I am not using the \graphicspath at all usually.